Existing query table data to word document report
I'm looking for some help on how to retrieve data from a query that utilizes combo boxes for relationships and filters. I want to take the data from this query and insert it into a Word document for a report.
Currently, my Access database is connected to a SQL database, which has several queries set up to populate the combo boxes. I can create a table that generates a report within Access, but I find the reporting tool in Access quite basic when it comes to formatting and images. That's why I'm considering using Word for the reporting.
I've attempted various methods to write VBA code to extract data from the query, but since the query relies on the combo boxes, it makes the data extraction a bit tricky.
code:
Private Sub Command81_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim appWord As Object
Dim docWord As Object
Dim rng As Object

    ' Open the database and query
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Service_Quote")
    
    ' Create a new Word document
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWord.Visible = True
    Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Add
    
    ' Add data to the Word document
    Set rng = docWord.Range
    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            rng.InsertAfter "Field1: " & !FullName & vbCrLf
            'rng.InsertAfter "Field2: " & !Field2 & vbCrLf
            'rng.InsertAfter "Field3: " & !Field3 & vbCrLf
            rng.InsertAfter vbCrLf
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set docWord = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing

End Sub

The code I have works perfectly with another query that simply pulls all the sales names from the existing table. However, because the other query is designed to use search criteria,

I encounter error code "3061."

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Options: 1) write filtered dataset to a 'temp' table; 2) use VBA QueryDefs to modify query object with static parameters to filter records.

You can also use tricks to allow form-based parameters in DAO recordsets

This question is similar to: Can I open a recordset using application-level features (user-defined functions, form-based parameters) in Access?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
